# How to make a lerna monorepo build directly for production?

Tags: javascript, lerna, yarn-workspaces

I have a fairly complex monorepo setup using learna.

Imagine I have multiple packages

```
"packages": [
    "@myorg/package1",
    "@otherorg/package2",
    "@anotherorg/package3",
    ...
]
```

The projects from my organization have both a `build` script and a `build:production` script that optimizes the output for production while the projects from the other organization only have a `build` script.

At the moment what this project does is to run `yarn build` followed by `yarn build:production` to build for production which works, but it's quite inefficient.

Is there a way to tell yarn or learn to call the `build:production` script if available and fallback to `build` if not?

Alternatively is there any way to reorganize the project configuration to make this happen?